# How to do an equivalent of "overlap" keyword of Django 2.2 in Django 1.11?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-views, django-orm

Suppose I have a model **"Books"** which has a field named **"locations_available"**. This field stores a list of locations in which a book is available. Now, I have a **query_list = ['US', 'Germany', 'Italy']**.

To find all the books which are available in **any** of these locations, I would do in Django 2.2 like this:

```
Books.objects.filter(locations_available__overlap=query_list)
```

Since Django 1.1 had no overlap feature, how would I do the same functionality there?

```
>>> Books.objects.create(name='X', locations=['India', 'Japan'])
>>> Books.objects.create(name='Y', locations=['US', 'Korea'])
>>> Books.objects.create(name='Z', locations=['Italy', 'Germany'])
>>> Books.objects.create(name='A', locations=['US', 'Germany', Italy])
```

Consider the above data, the following datas should be returned:

```
name='Y', locations=['US', 'Korea']

name='Z', locations=['Italy', 'Germany']

name='A', locations=['US', 'Germany', 'Italy']
```

Note that the book with **name='X'** is not returned as it has no overlapping with any of the locations in the query_list.

Check out this for more details: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#overlap

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit confused. You're talking about Django **1.11** or Django **1.1** ?

Comment: if you are using 1.11 or 1.10 both have the overlap lookup available. have you even tried it in 1.1x

Comment: I'm using Django 1.11.4

Comment: I've tried the overlap lookup but it doesn't work. I get an empty QuerySet.

Comment: The `__overlap` lookup exists, is is already part of Django since at least 1.8.

Comment: Can you show the `print((query_list, type(query_list)))`? It looks to me something is not correct with your parameter.

Comment: If it wasn't supported in your version of Django you wouldn't just get an empty queryset, you'd get an error.

Answer (score 1):

> Since Django 1.1 (Sic) had no overlap feature, how would I do the same functionality there?

[django-1.10](/questions/tagged/django-1.10) *has* an [**`__overlap`** lookup [Django-1.10-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#overlap). It even already has this feature since [django-1.8](/questions/tagged/django-1.8), see for example the [documentation [Django-1.8-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#overlap), and the [source code [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.8.x/django/contrib/postgres/lookups.py#L28).

The documentation clearly demonstrates how this works:

> ```
> >>> Post.objects.create(name='First post', tags=['thoughts', 'django'])
> >>> Post.objects.create(name='Second post', tags=['thoughts'])
> >>> Post.objects.create(name='Third post', tags=['tutorial', 'django'])
>
> >>> Post.objects.filter(tags__overlap=['thoughts'])
> [<Post: First post>, <Post: Second post>]
>
> >>> Post.objects.filter(tags__overlap=['thoughts', 'tutorial'])
> [<Post: First post>, <Post: Second post>, <Post: Third post>]
> ```

It thus seems to suggest, that either your `locations_available` is *not* an `ArrayField((models.CharField(...), ...)`, or your `query_list` is *not* a list of `str`ings.